# Password confirmation on app launch

Tags: iphone, ios

I recently changed the email address and the password for my apple ID. Since then, when I launch an app, it occasionally asks me for my apple ID password. Even apps that I've successfully launched before, might ask me again. This is very annoying and I'm loosing hope that this is going to stop.

What can I do about it?

Oh, it's an iPhone 6s with iOS 12.1.

Comment: sometimes a simple Restart will fix that.

Comment: Logging out of iCloud also helps sometimes. Then, of course, log back in. :-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 Reboot your phone**

Restart your phone by holding the on/off button for up to 10 seconds then slide to turn off your phone. Then hold the on/off button till the apple logo appears.

**Option 2 Sign out of Apple ID and Sign Back In**

If just rebooting your iPhone doesn't fix the issue, you can try signing out of the Apple ID and then sign in back. Many times, this method works out well. To do this:

[image: sign out]

**Option 3 Reset your Apple ID password**

Sometimes, resetting the password might help fix this problem. To do this, launch Safari browser, and type this appleid.apple.com and hit enter.

Now, click on Forgot Apple ID or Password

[image: reset password]

Comment: A restart seems to have worked for now. If the problem reoccurs, I’ll try the other options.